# Table: How to adjust the text in the same row to be horizontally aligned?

Tags: tables, pdftex

These are the codes:

```
\documentclass{article}
 
 
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}%

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X*{2}{|>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}}
   \Xhline{0.8pt}
 
 
%  \cline{1-8}
Shrinkage estimator  &\makecell{Prior} & \makecell{Posterior estimator} \\
\hline 
estimate1 &\makecell{ \(\beta_{i}\sim\Normal{0}{\frac{1}{\lambda}}}&\makecell{$\left(1-\frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda}\right)\hat{\beta}_{i}, \lambda > 0$}  \\
estimate2  &\makecell{\(\beta_{i}\sim \mathrm{Laplace}(0, \frac{1}{\lambda})\)}&\makecell{$\mathrm{sign}(\hat{\beta}_i)(|\hat{\beta}_i| - \lambda)^+$}   \\
estimate3  &\makecell{\(\beta_{i}\sim \Normal{M}{A}\)}&\makecell{$\left(1-\frac{N-3}{\sum_i^N(\hat{\beta}_{i}-\bar{\beta})^2}\right)^+(\hat{\beta}_{i}-\bar{\beta})+\bar{\beta}$}    \\  
\hline
\end{tabularx}
 \label{tab3}
\hfill \break
 
\end{document}
```

The table generated by the codes is:
[image]

However for the third row of this table, since the entry in the rightmost side need larger space, then it makes the third row of this table no longer horizontally aligned. What I want is

[image]

which the text in the same row are horizontally aligned. Could anyone indicate me how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: I suspect there is a blank line caused by the \makecell not fitting into the X column.  Fix that and it should work. In other words, stop using X columns for single lines of text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve it making the first column `l` type and using `makecell` to have  the first column head split over two lines:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Laplace}{Laplace}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Normal}{Normal}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sign}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}%
\setcellgapes{4pt}

\begin{document}

\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l*{2}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}@{}}
   \Xhline{0.8pt}
\makecell[lc]{Shrinkage\\ estimator} &\makecell{Prior} & \makecell{Posterior estimator} \\
\hline
estimate1 &\(\beta_{i}\sim\Normal\Bigl(0,\mfrac{1}{\lambda}\Bigr)\)&\makecell{$\Bigl(1-\mfrac{\lambda}{1+\lambda}\Bigr)\hat{\beta}_{i}, \lambda > 0$} \\
estimate2 &\makecell{\(\beta_{i}\sim \Laplace\Bigl(0, \mfrac{1}{\lambda}\Bigr)\)}&\makecell{$\sign\bigl(\hat{\beta}_i)(|\hat{\beta}_i| - \lambda\bigr)^+$} \\
estimate3 &\makecell{\(\beta_{i}\sim \Normal(M, A)\)}&\makecell{$\Bigl(1-\mfrac{N-3}{\medop\sum_i^N(\hat{\beta}_{i}-\bar{\beta})^2}\Bigr)^{\!+\!}\!(\hat{\beta}_{i}-\bar{\beta})+\bar{\beta}$}
\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
 \label{tab3}
\hfill \break

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

slightly modified [Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908/bernard) answer:

- defined new column type `C`
- put last two columns into "math" mode, consequently math expression not need to be enclosed by `(` and `)`
- resize widths of the second and third column
- remove `\makecell{...}` around equations in cells

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Laplace}{Laplace}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Normal}{Normal}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sign}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}%
\setcellgapes{4pt}

\begin{document}

\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l| >{\hsize=0.4\hsize $}C<{$}
                              | >{\hsize=0.6\hsize $}C<{$}
                             @{}}
   \Xhline{0.8pt}
\makecell[lc]{Shrinkage\\ estimator}
            &\text{Prior}
            & \text{Posterior estimator} \\
\hline
estimate1   & \beta_{i}\sim\Normal\Bigl(0,\mfrac{1}{\lambda}\Bigr)
            & \Bigl(1-\mfrac{\lambda}{1+\lambda}\Bigr)\hat{\beta}_{i}, \lambda > 0       \\
estimate2   & \beta_{i}\sim \Laplace\Bigl(0, \mfrac{1}{\lambda}\Bigr)
            & \sign\bigl(\hat{\beta}_i)(|\hat{\beta}_i| - \lambda\bigr)^{+}              \\
estimate3   & \beta_{i}\sim \Normal
            & \Bigl(1-\mfrac{N-3}{\medop\sum_i^N(\hat{\beta}_{i}-\bar{\beta})^2}\Bigr)^{+}
                (\hat{\beta}_{i}-\bar{\beta})+\bar{\beta}
            \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]